# Implementing faccessat() on Mac OS X, how do I construct a new path from given the directory file descriptor and pathname?

Tags: c, macos, posix

I wish to implement the POSIX 2008 function

```
int faccessat(int dirfd, const char *pathname, int mode, int flags)
```

on Mac OS X. According to the Linux manpage for the function:

```
   If the pathname given in pathname is relative, then it is interpreted relative
   to the directory referred to by the file descriptor dirfd (rather than
   relative to the current working directory of the calling process, as is done
   by access(2) for a relative pathname).
```

How can I construct a new path from the given directory file descriptor and pathname?

Comment: Does MacOSX have anything like Linux /proc? On Linux, you can "emulate" all the `*at()` functions on old kernels using `/proc/self/fd/%d/%s`.

Comment: @R.. unfortunately no, Mac OS X does not implement procfs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Mac OS X you can get a path for the directory, if available, using [`fcntl(dirfd, F_GETPATH, dirpath)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/fcntl.2.html); `dirpath` must have a size `MAXPATHLEN` or larger.  If the supplied path is relative you could then append `"/"` and the supplied path to the directory path.  However, this may produce a string that is longer than `MAXPATHLEN`.

Another way to do it is to use [`fchdir()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/fchdir.2.html) to change your working directory to that directory, and then use the relative path directly.  Of course this will change the current directory of your process.  If necessary you can save it first by opening the original current directory `"."` and then use `fchdir()` again with that saved file descriptor after you are done to restore the original current directory.  However that may still be an issue if your program is multithreaded and the other threads rely on the current directory.

Comment: Option 1 seems good. I can manually check if the total length of the new path is greater than MAXPATHLEN and if so set errno to ENAMETOOLONG and return -1.